# Python regex tokenizer for simple expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wrote this regex that splits the expression 'res=3+x_sum*11' into lexemes

```
import re
print(re.findall('(\w+)(=)(\d+)(\*|\+)(\w+)(\*|\+)(\d+)', 'res=3+x_sum*11'))
```

with my output looking like this:

```
[('res', '=', '3', '+', 'x_sum', '*', '11')]
```

but i want re.findall to return a list of the lexemes and their tokens so that each lexeme is in its own group. That output should look like this:

```
[('', 'res', ''), ('', '', '='), ('3', '', ''), ('', '', '+'),

('', 'x_sum', ''), ('', '', '*'), ('11', '', '')]
```

How do i get re.findall to return an output like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may tokenize the string using

```
re.findall(r'(\d+)|([^\W\d]+)|(\W)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qpeQcC/1/). Note that `re.findall` returns a list of tuples once the pattern contains several capturing groups. The pattern above contains 3 capturing groups, thus, each tuple contains 3 elements: 1+ digits, 1+ letters/underscores, or a non-word char.

**More details**

- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `([^\W\d]+)` - Capturing group 2: 1+ chars other than non-word and digit chars (letters or underscores)
- `|` - or
- `(\W)` - Capturing group 3: a non-word char.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OeTDG1):

```
import re
rx = r"(\d+)|([^\W\d]+)|(\W)"
s = "res=3+x_sum*11"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => [('', 'res', ''), ('', '', '='), ('3', '', ''), ('', '', '+'), ('', 'x_sum', ''), ('', '', '*'), ('11', '', '')]
```